# How can I check if a chart is a line chart?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am attempting to check if a selected shape is a chart, and subsequently, if it is a line chart.

**My attempt:**

```
Sub ChartSmooth(ByVal control As IRibbonControl)

Dim activeShape As Shape

'Determine Which Shape is Active
If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionShapes Then
'Loop in case multiples shapes selected
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
         Set activeShape = shp ' First shape selected
         Exit For
    Next

'Now, reformat the selected shape if it is a chart
    With activeShape
        If .HasChart Then
            If .ChartType = xlLine Then
                MsgBox "True" ' I will eventually put some code here to do something
            End If
        End If
    End With ' activeShape

End If

ActiveWindow.Selection.Unselect

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just add .Chart in front of .ChartType:

```
If .HasChart Then
    If .Chart.ChartType = xlLine Then
```